# Appending a form to third-party website via external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, external

We are given a website, allowing its subscribers to post plain text & external links only at own profiles. More than this, the posted links are being carefully validated for non-URL symbols and, if found, loose `href` in html :)) Here what it looks like,1

```
<a class="link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="https://xxx.yyy.zzz/png.png">
</a>
```

i'd been trying to pack js-jquery modal popup call within given field length, but no soap.

Anyway, I can post a valid external link, but it opens new page in new tab:

```
<a class="link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" href="https://abc.def.ghi/index.php?mmm=100&nnn=100">
    <img src="https://xxx.yyy.zzz/png.png">
</a>
```

while I want it, for example, to pop up the modal over parent site. Any ideas? XD

Answer (score 0):

With "pop up modal over parent site", do you mean just not opening a new tab and opening it instead of your site?

If yes, remove the `target="_blank"` attribute.

If no, please try to explain your question better because I can't really follow your way of thinking.

Comment: The answer is "yes",  but I can't remove `target="_blank"` from third-party site :D not mentioning `rel="noopener noreferrer"` The aim is to make my modal available to everybody by clicking the given link The trick is to override link `target` & `rel`-set behaviour from outside.